# How detect modified repeater item in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, repeater

I'm using [this jquery plugin](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater) in my Laravel website and this is a repeater field plugin. I'm wondering how can I detect a edited or removed repeater item field in my edit post page so I can update or destroy that specific item in the database?! I'm asking this because names get reindexed dynamically by plugin if an item is removed.

Comment: Now that I think more, maybe I can do this by adding a hidden input with the value of item id for each repeater items.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding a hidden input with the value of item id for each repeater items.